# Data is not populating in Table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am facing issue while displaying data in table.

I am using a customservice to fetch data from a json file and then inserting that data into $rootScope of an object.

But when I run the view,it comes blank with no errors.In the view,i am using below line of code in the view to iterate the array of objects "books"

Please guide me.

controller.js

```
Controllers.controller('BookListCtrl_Student', ['$scope','$rootScope','$http','$location','BookData',
function ($scope, $rootScope, $http, $location, BookData) {
    $rootScope.books=[];
    $rootScope.books.push(BookData.getData());
    $scope.bookLists = ['All Books', 'Available Books'];
    $scope.selection = $scope.bookLists[0];

    $scope.backToLogin = function() {
        $location.path("/main");
    }
}    
]);
```

customservice.js

```
Controllers.factory('BookData',['$http',function(http){
return {
    getData: function() {
        return http.get('data/books.json').then(function(result){               
            return result.data;               
            });
    }
};
}
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you do *$rootScope.books.push(BookData.getData())* it calls your *getData()*, but it never executes the promise. To fix it you would need to handle the promise within the controller and assign the data then.

**customservice.js**

```
return http.get('data/books.json');
```

**controller.js**

```
BookData.getData().then(function(resp){
   $rootScope.books.push(resp.data);
})
```

Heres a plunker with a quick example - https://plnkr.co/edit/ivdLd9wilmWW8oUnrMsh?p=preview